# CSS table right margin in scrollable div

Tags: html, css

I have div with "overflow: scroll" and fixed-size table inside.
I need to add empty space below and on the right of the table.
I'm using following code, however it adds space only below table, right margin doesn't work for some reason...

Is it possible without changing html structure?

```
<style>
  div{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
  table{
    table-layout: fixed;
    background: red;
    margin-bottom: 20px; /* working */
    margin-right: 20px; /* not working */
  }
  td{
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
  }
</style>
<div>
  <table>
    <tr><td>a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>b</td></tr>
    <tr><td>c</td></tr>
    <tr><td>d</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7cdzh0cn/

Also I have tried adding paddings to DIV however they don't work - DIV only increases in size.

**Note**: I don't want change size of DIV or size of table - they should stay the same. Only thing I want to empty space inside DIV after table on the right and below it.

Comment: is there any fiddle please let me know or screenshot of it??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could reset the default `display:table` to `inline-table`.

```
table {
  display: inline-table;
}
```

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    overflow: scroll;
}
table {
    display: inline-table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    background: red;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
td {
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <table>
        <tr><td>a</td></tr>
        <tr><td>b</td></tr>
        <tr><td>c</td></tr>
        <tr><td>d</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Only one person who really helped! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The `div`, haven't the correct `width`. Adding `120px` (`20px` to margin), and resizing the table to `100px` this work.

**CSS:**

```
  div{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px; /* Updated*/
    height: 120px; /* Updated*/
    background: blue;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
  table{
    table-layout: fixed;
    background: red;
    margin-bottom: 20px; 
    margin-right: 20px; 
    width: 100px; /* added */
  }
  td{
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 150px;

  }
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jukxL3f2/1/)</kbd>

Comment: Update the `width` to your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the width attribute for the div.
Everything will work fine as expected.

```
div{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to add **padding-left** in your table style

replace your table css

```
 table{
 table-layout: fixed;
 background: red;
 margin-bottom: 20px; /* working */
 margin-right: 20px; /* not working */
 padding-left: 23px;
}
```

here jsfiffle demo :
http://jsfiddle.net/sL8zxLbn/